# Populating jQuery UI autocomplete list with element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery UI to create an autocomplete search bar,

I'm attempting to modify the following to populate the list of available tags based on the ID name of elements on the page,

```
var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
        ];
```

For example on the page, I will have an element such as

```
<div class="items" id="Get milk">Don't forget to get milk on way home from work</div>
```

Once the list is populated with these element id's and a particular id is autocompleted I will be setting all other elements to `display: none;`

Comment: What isn't working? What code have you tried?

Comment: Don't use spaces in id's: `id="Get milk"`. Rather change it to `id="GetMilk"`.

Comment: Clarify further what's the problem here or create an example on jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: var availableTags = [ $(".items").attr('id'); ];

Comment: JS fiddle here,
http://jsfiddle.net/qWMpw/
thank you

Comment: What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Populating the available tags based on id.

Comment: When using var availableTags = [ $(".items").attr('id') ];
I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined

Comment: Your fiddle has nothing to do with your question as it is above, and the fiddle produces no error that I see as it is now.  You do not even have the same framework in your fiddle.  Please update your fiddle and question to properlly express your error condition.

Comment: fiddle updated, I'm expecting 
var availableTags = [ $(".items").attr('id'); ]
to provide an autocomplete search list of ID names. i.e. Grab a Sandwich.

How can the code be modified to populate the available tags correctly?

Comment: Perhaps I need something similar as http://jsfiddle.net/tGFeZ/4/ But how might I tailor it!?

Comment: @user1900791: In your fiddle none of the `.items` actually have `id` attributes. Is that a mistake?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, The below applies an `id`attribute based on the content the div wraps, the inner html.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each($('.items'), function() {
        $(this).attr('id', $(this).html());
    });`

Comment: @user1900791: This is doable, but `id`s are not allowed to have spaces. Could you use a `data-*` attribute instead?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, thanks Andrew, yeah data works too. Any idea what javaScript I would use to enter this 'data' into the array of available tags as above applied I have tried '[ $(".items").attr('data'); ]' Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [`$("...").map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to transform your source array-like object (in this case a jQuery object filled with DOM nodes matching your `.items` selector) into an array that jQueryUI autocomplete can work with. Something like this should work:

```
var source = $(".items").map(function () {
    return $(this).data("id");
}).get();

$("#auto").autocomplete({
    source: source        
});
```

Assuming you're using a `data-id` attribute, so your markup would look something like this:

```
<div class="items" data-id="Get Milk">Get Milk on the way home</div>
<div class="items" data-id="Drop by Phil's">Drop by Phils house</div>
<div class="items" data-id="Grab a Sandwich">Grab a sandwich</div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/25/